# Flot: Show a minimum amount of ticks

Tags: javascript, jquery, flot

Using [flot charts](http://www.flotcharts.org/) I would like to specify a minimum of ticks to show on the y-axis. In my case I would like to always show at least 10 ticks (values 1-10), but if my y-axis max exceeds 10 then I would like flot to draw the chart with its normal tick algorithm. I currently have it sort of working by specifying a function for the ticks paramater.

```
ticks: function(axis){
           var ticks = [];
           if(axis.max < 10){
                ticks = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];
           }
           else{
             for(var i = 1; i < axis.max; i++){
                 ticks.push(i);
             }
           }
           return ticks;
},
```

The problem with this is that I get a lot more ticks than I want when the `axis.max` is greater than 10. Is there a way to avoid this?

I originally thought I could return null, but flot is expecting an array to be returned. :(

Comment: What you have explained and what that function does are contradictory.  Try removing that `else` statement and change the `if` condition to a less or equal than i.e. `<=`

Comment: @Alexander The else statement will create the tick array of values up to the `axis.max` if I remove it then I will only have tick values 1-10. This is not what I want. I want tick values up to the y-axis max. I just don't want them in increments of 1. I want flot to use its default algorithm if possible.

Comment: No, that's not true. If you remove it, it will return an empty array. Hence, the `else` statement is on the way. Remove it. As for the rest you need to add the property dynamically if returning `null` doesn't do the trick

Comment: @alexander good point. I will try that.

Comment: Not exactly a duplicate, but very similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17723904/flot-charts-xaxis-minimum-length

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want the default functionality for tick generation you can call the `tickGenerator` function of the axes. It is much cleaner than working with a piece of code you don't maintain. So in your case, you could do this:

```
ticks: function(axis){
   return axis.max < 10 ? [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10] : axis.tickGenerator(axis); 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems that default Flot algorithm goes like that (see `setupTickGeneration` function:

```
noTicks = 0.3 * Math.sqrt(axis.direction == "x" ? canvasWidth : canvasHeight);
```

so maybe something like that would work here (DISCLAIMER - not really tested, not sure if you have all needed vars in this scope and the math is just to sketch the solution:

```
ticks: function(axis){
       var ticks = [];
       if(axis.max < 10){
            ticks = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];
       }
       else{

         noTicks = 0.3 * Math.sqrt(canvasHeight);
         interval = Math.round(axis.max / noTicks); 
         for(var i = 1; i <= noTicks; i++){
             ticks.push(i * interval);
         }
       }
       return ticks;
},
```

Comment: Duh on my part, and awesome on yours!

Comment: Thanks :) Actually you might check if writing a plugin around processOptions hook would be a cleaner option for this

Answer (score 0):

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17723904/flot-charts-xaxis-minimum-length):

```
ticks: 16
```

but I haven't tried it.

Comment: Thanks for the help, but no go with that. It rounds down if my axis.max is less than 10.

Comment: So use it when `max>10`