# Flot dynamically show/hide xaxis label based on data

Tags: javascript, jquery, graph, flot

I need help about the xaxis ticks label..again..I am stuck with this problem.
I want to hide the xaxis ticklabel and bar when data is 0.

```
$(function() {

var statement = [
    [gd(2018, 6, 1), 0],
    [gd(2018, 6, 2), 2000000],
    [gd(2018, 6, 3), 240000000],
    [gd(2018, 6, 4), 260000000],
    [gd(2018, 6, 5), 280000000],
    [gd(2018, 6, 6), 300000000],
    [gd(2018, 6, 7), 320000000],
    [gd(2018, 6, 8), 0],
    [gd(2018, 6, 9), 0],
    [gd(2018, 6, 10), 0],
    [gd(2018, 6, 11), 0],
    [gd(2018, 6, 12), 0],
    [gd(2018, 6, 13), 0],
    [gd(2018, 6, 14), 0],
    [gd(2018, 6, 15), 0],
    [gd(2018, 6, 16), 0],
    [gd(2018, 6, 17), 0],
    [gd(2018, 6, 18), 0],
    [gd(2018, 6, 19), 0],
    [gd(2018, 6, 20), 0],
    [gd(2018, 6, 21), 0],
    [gd(2018, 6, 22), 0],
    [gd(2018, 6, 23), 0],
    [gd(2018, 6, 24), 0],
    [gd(2018, 6, 25), 0],
    [gd(2018, 6, 26), 0],
    [gd(2018, 6, 27), 0],
    [gd(2018, 6, 28), 0],
    [gd(2018, 6, 29), 0],
    [gd(2018, 6, 30), 0]
];
var dataset = [{
    label: "Electricity Consumption",
    data: statement,
    color: "#ffa500",
    bars: {
        show: true,
        align: "center",
        barWidth: 24 * 60 * 60 * 600,
        lineWidth: 1
    }
}];


var options = {
    xaxis: {
        mode: "time",
        tickSize: [1, "day"],
        timeformat: "%d %b",
        tickLength: 0,
        rotateTicks: 135,
        axisLabel: "",
        axisLabelUseCanvas: true,
        axisLabelFontSizePixels: 8,
        axisLabelFontFamily: "Verdana, Arial",
        axisLabelPadding: 5,
        color: "black"
    },
    yaxes: [{
        position: "left",
        color: "black",
        axisLabel: "Usage",
        axisLabelUseCanvas: true,
        axisLabelFontSizePixels: 12,
        axisLabelFontFamily: "Verdana, Arial",
        axisLabelPadding: 3,
        tickDecimals: 0,
        tickFormatter: function numberWithCommas(x) {
            return x.toString().replace(/\B(?=(?:\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
        }
    }],
    legend: {
        container: $("#legendContainer"),
        noColumns: 2,
        labelBoxBorderColor: "#000000",
        position: "nw"
    },
    grid: {
        hoverable: true,
        borderWidth: 1,
        backgroundColor: {
            colors: ["#ffffff", "#EDF5FF"]
        }
    }
};


$.plot($("#placeholder"), dataset, options);

function gd(year, month, day) {
    console.log(Date.UTC(year, month - 1, day), new Date(Date.UTC(year, month - 1, day)));
    return Date.UTC(year, month - 1, day);
}
```

});

This is the corresponding [jfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cewmuv17/) (courtesy of Raidri).

I want to hide label from July 8-31 since usage is 0 but still show July 1.

Is there a way to do this? I only this setting

```
xaxis: {show:false}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To show only some tick labels you can use a conditional `tickFormatter` function for the x axis, for example

```
tickFormatter: function (tickValue, axis) {
    // looking for datapoint at this tick
    var value = dataset[0].data.find(dp => dp[0] == tickValue);
    if ((tickValue == dataset[0].data[0][0]) || (value && value[1] > 0.0)) {
        // first tick on the axis or a tick where the value is greater zero
        var tickDate = new Date(tickValue);
        // manually setting the tick format
        return (tickDate.getDate() < 10 ? ('0' + tickDate.getDate()) : tickDate.getDate()) + '<br />' + monthNames[tickDate.getMonth()];
    }
    else {
        return '';
    }
}
```

See this [updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cewmuv17/3/) for the full example.

Comment: Hi @Raidri! It's you who helped me in my previous question! Thank you again!!! Thank you for the 'statement.filter()'! 

My question is very misleading what I mean is to retain the 30 ticks/bar but hide the xaxis label for June 8-31.

I found a duplicate question but unfortunately, the solution was not posted. :(

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17723904/flot-charts-xaxis-minimum-length

I hope you help me point to right direction!

Comment: The updated answer is the exact one that I needed! I just started with Flot and your inputs are a a great help!  I'll be studying your code inputs too. Thank you again!